# Undertake Employment

Tags: meaning, usage, verbs

I have a question about the usage of "*undertake employment*" [here](http://www.medicinternational.uk.com/eligibility-to-undertake-employment-in-the-uk):

> There are few employers currently offering a certificate of sponsorship to ***undertake employment***.

I cannot find "*undertake*" used with "*employment*" in dictionaries.  Could the usage in the example be a regional idiom or an error?

Comment: It's a perfectly natural usage, particularly since it echoes *explore your **eligibility to undertake employment** in the United Kingdom* two sentences earlier. Why exactly do you have a problem matching the usage to [these definitions of **undertake**?](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/undertake)

Answer (score 1):

"To undertake" is to commit oneself, sometimes with an implication that what you are committing yourself to is a burden. In this case, to undertake employment is to agree to accept a job, and in this context it is neutral, with no positive or negative connotations.

It is definitely not an error, and if it is a regional idiom it is a very widespread one. I don't find it to be odd or regional at all, though it is a little formal. You would probably never use this in a conversation, or even hear it spoken aloud, but in a document such as the one you are reading it is very common.

Answer (score 0):

The wording sounds a bit awkward to me, but is technically correct.

Guarantee:

> to warrant or guarantee (followed by a clause):
>
> The sponsors undertake that their candidate meets all the requirements.

So you may be able to reword the phrasing to:

> There are few employers currently offering a certificate of sponsorship to <s>undertake</s> warrant employment.

Comment: that is the wrong meaning of undertake in this context. It is the employee who undertakes employment, not the sponsor/employer. It does not mean "warrant" here.  See the first meaning in the dictionary you are quoting -  *undertook the job*.

Answer (score 0):

The word employment means the work or job you do or give to someone.

The sentence means that there are few employers that offer a certificate of sponsorship (work permit) accepting the responsibility for giving employment (work).